# Can connectivity be less than min cut/degree?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, combinatorial-optimization, expander-graphs

Suppose we have a graph with min-cut $\lambda$ and minimum degree $> \lambda$.

1. Is it possible for there to be a vertex that is at most $\lambda$-connected to every other vertex in the graph?
2. Suppose we contract every pair of vertices that are more than $\lambda$-connected.  In this contracted graph, can there be a vertex of degree more than $\lambda$?

Edit: Thanks for the helpful reply about infinite graphs, but I am wondering about finite graphs.

Comment: Are your graphs finite?

Comment: Asking because, if graphs can be infinite, you can take a chain infinite in both directions, $\lambda=1$, min degree $2$, and every vertex is only $1$-connected to every other vertex.

Comment: I am asking about finite graphs, thanks for asking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q1:** Yes. I'm not sure if your "min-cut $\lambda$" refers to minimum vertex-cut or minimum edge-cut, but in either case a minimal example (in number of vertices) is the following 7-vertex graph, which has both vertex- and edge-connectivity $\lambda=1$, minimum degree $2$, and vertex $1$ is only $1$-connected to every other vertex.

[image: Example graph]

**Q2:** Yes, with the following 10-vertex graph, with $\lambda=1$ and minimum degree $2$. If you contract all 2-connected pairs, vertex $1$ will still have degree $3$.

[image: Second example graph]

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful!